# cffi: How do i send the address of a character of a string to a C function?

Tags: python, cffi

i am actually writing a python program with cffi module to test my C/ASM library, and i managed to make it work. But i don't know how to access the address of a character in the middle of a string to pass it to my lib function. For exemple:

```
def my_bzero_test():
   str = b"hello world"
   print(str)
   lib.ft_bzero(str, 5)
   print(str)
```

that prints:

> b'hello world'
>
> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 world'

But how can i test something like:

```
def my_bzero_test():
   str = b"hello world"
   print(str)
   lib.ft_bzero(str + 5, 5) # C-style accessing &str[5]
   print(str)
```

i tried different stuff, like:

```
def my_bzero_test():
    str = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"hello world")
    addr = ctypes.addressof(str)
    print(hex(addr))
    print(str)
    lib.ft_bzero(addr + 5, 5)
    print(str)
```

output:

> TypeError: initializer for ctype 'void *' must be a cdata pointer, not int

also tried with id(), with no success...

I am not very familiar with python but it seems liek it is not a trivial utilisation of it, so little help here would be appreciated, thanks !

Python 3.7.0

Comment: Don’t edit an answer into your question; post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

ok found the solution use ffi.new() and ffi.tostring()

```
str = ffi.new("char[]", b"hello world")
print(ffi.string(str))
lib.ft_bzero(str + 5, 5)
print(ffi.string(str))
```

output:

> b'hello world'
>
> b'hello'